# Сложное правило редиректа с http на https Yii2

Tags: php, .htaccess, сервер, redirect

Добрый вечер! Имею проект на yii2. Думаю каждый сталкивался с проблемой сделать так, чтобы приложение смотрело в папку /web. Так вот, [для этого есть правило (кликабельно).](https://toster.ru/q/210872)

Но оно не учитывает наличие SSL сертификата, а мне нужно сделать так, чтобы все запросы переадресовывались на https.

На текущий момент файлы .htaccess выглядят так:

В корне сайта:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

В папке /web:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . index.php
```

В .htaccess в корне сайта я пробовал так:

```
RewriteRule . https://%{SERVER_NAME}/web/index.php
```

И все работает, но в адресной строке я вижу `https://site.com/web/index.php`

А по дефолту `web/index.php` не видно (ибо так красивее). Как сконфигурировать все это дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По правильному, нужно было бы DocumentRoot указать непосредственно на директорию web/, но можно обойтись и без этого.
Для этого в .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

В web/.htaccess можно ничего не менять. Дефолтный подойдет. А в конфиге config/web.php, необходимо добавить в блок components -> request:

```
'baseUrl'=> ''
```

Это должно дать нужный результат.

**UPDATE:**

Поднял у себя yii2 basic. Сделал так:

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [QSA,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

web/.htaccess как в исходном сообщении, и в components -> request прописать нужно `'baseUrl'=> ''`

Comment: Либо я вас не понял, либо вы меня. Сделать папку /web webroot-ом не проблема, но со стороны, так скажем, заказчика, есть ограничения. А ваш конфиг не отличается от моего и просто делает редирект на папку веб, а мне нужно, чтобы он делал редирект на эту папку с https, даже если юзер ввел адрес с http

Comment: В .htaccess добавьте:
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
И убедитесь, что вы внесли изменения в config/web.php.

Comment: добавил и убедился в изменениях config/web ('baseUrl'=> ''), но нужного результата не дало. Если заходить с https - то все работает, а если нет, то адрес становится таким: site.com//web

Comment: Дополнил мой комментарий, и у меня есть ощущение, что у вас закешировался редирект. Попробуйте после правок .htaccess открыть в другом браузере.

Answer (score 0):

Все можно организовать гораздо проще. 
У хостера обычно есть доменная папка сайта типа ~/www/your-site.ru/index.php. Первое что надо сделать, это переименовать папку где лежит index.php аналогично названию доменной папки у хостера -> /your-site.ru/

Если тестируете у хостера, то надо в папку  ~/www/ залить всю структуру папок сайта и корень сайта будет доменная папка ~/www/your-site.ru/. Т.е. файлы движка Yii буду на один уровень выше.

Если разрабатываете сайт локально, то надо указать в конфиге Apache папку виртуального хоста так, чтобы это была доменная ваша папка /your-site.ru/, например так (пример из OpenServer):

```
<VirtualHost *:%httpport%>
    DocumentRoot    "%hostdir%/your-site.ru"
    ServerName      "%host%"
    ServerAlias     "%host%" %aliases%
    ScriptAlias     /cgi-bin/ "%hostdir%/cgi-bin/"
</VirtualHost>
```

B затем убрать все настройки RewriteRule из .htaccess, т.к. и без них все будет работать.

**Добавлено**

Если этот вариант не устраивает, тогда правим .htaccess так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php [R]
RewriteRule /web/index\.php$ /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Так я сделать не могу из-за ряда ограничений

Comment: Добавил вариант с .htaccess, если заработает отпишитесь

Comment: К сожалению, не заработало :( http://screenshot.ru/upload/image/SHsY

Answer (score 0):

Готово, помогла тех поддержка

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ /web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ /web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ /web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```